# netbeans jtable refreshing when table connected to database using bind property

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have connected a jTable to a database using the binding property of the table. When I update a record it doesn't show up in the table. Many people have created their tables using code and added data to it using code itself. So I could not find a way to do the needful. Is there any way I could refresh the data in the jtable in the way I have set things up?

Comment: Post your full code.

Comment: I went with the conventional code to populate data now it's working fine thank you :)